# Angular sending access token to Asp.net Web API not working if the email address has a '+' in it

Tags: angularjs, security, oauth, asp.net-web-api2

I have security working fine in an application, except when a user tries to login with a '+' in their email.

The access token looks fine (when the email contains a + it looks like this):

```
Bearer 8BGpt_KkEp-_6U5tUdKqK1xLCQBaWzHcxDT9RRKkbzoF2fHCUNhRL3U-fpLdQIuSXm8RcTOH4ZY3a0UZH6-6IgXxx_ojgyL26179JovRm5xQSZD7ANxLvvdU3ubfcpzSr4tw-sza37UaJh7xDFB8eH0NA9Djt7Ik8Ebxdin7u-n76InCulRAV6xMWgXfF9bwoU8MsV3lrh_zhnxYGnx3O7QUNQ740NUJLHJYH12rBth16CA1AXSF86rA5rUB7vJ7yK09k_FJTifyuldTeFHJHsyscnEIQxGozbf3x1cmZowkiK4Q1r8W0M8uz25m8j_tuMrWawTqYJNZiTuI9afW38WWQ4BRLkQF7TwoMOgZQ-f1K_3W8Zy3x-OsKdQS4i9CapvKe1utCscZVroByvyD9SvpILGiZGTjGD_zCAm8KerMPT5GNOb07kPGV_167PHEXm0TGaJbCelb5gLgXbMXv3GxBQLnYIfPUXCBaKx4UFkY8kFMPs9MxFcGY81p67rfnjeswBZ3PW6fDFTf9U_I8g
```

However, when I try to send a secure request with this access token, I get the response:

```
status: 401
"{"Message":"Authorization has been denied for this request."}"
```

As said above, it works without any issue if I remove the plus. This seems to be a Wep API issue rather than an Angular issue.

I found that the methods encodeUrl and decodeUrl to not stop the space from being change to a plus. I have tried the following in the c# code to switch the space to a plus:

```
var registerEmail = model.email.Replace(' ', '+');
```

This is used in both the login and register actions.

Perhaps it is not possible to use a + in an email in OAuth in Web API 2?

Comment: how are you generating the token? how are you sending the email to your api? Have you tried url encoding the email before sending it to the api?

Comment: I've tried using encodeUrl when sending it and it continue to turn the plus into a space. Instead, I've got a line in the c# code: 

var registerEmail = model.email.Replace(' ', '+');

which is used on register and the token endpoint to login

Comment: Note: I plan to use encoding via the web api eventually rather than just handling the plus, but to try to find the cause of the issue, I find this method works fine

Comment: You're having a problem similar to this one: http://www.wwml.tech/questions/4901140/plus-sign-in-base64-encode64-output; plus is a valid Base64 character but is not used in all implementations. I think you can use an HttpModule, read the headers and apply the replacement there

Comment: The token _looks_ fine to you and me, but it didn't decode successfully in [any](https://jwt.io/) of [the](http://calebb.net/) online [tools](https://www.jsonwebtoken.io/) I tried it with.  I think there's a problem with your token generation (unless all decoding algorithms used in those sites are also broken?)

Answer (score 0):

It seems to be a bug in asp.net roles. I am not sure of a clear solution. However, for the time being, encoding the username as follows before storing it on register and when logging in:

```
public static class UsernameEncodingService
{
    public static string returnEncodedUsername(string email)
    {
        var emailAsLower = email.ToLowerInvariant();
        var encodedEmail = Base64Encode(emailAsLower);
        var encodedEmailWithoutEquals = encodedEmail.Replace("=", "213");
        var encodedEmailWithoutPlus = encodedEmailWithoutEquals.Replace("+", "214");
        return encodedEmailWithoutEquals;
    }

    private static string Base64Encode(string plainText)
    {
        var plainTextBytes = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(plainText);
        return System.Convert.ToBase64String(plainTextBytes);
    }
}
```